# I can't see why my review wasn't helpful

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-suspension, specific-edit

I got hungry on steward medal recently so I try to review a lot of posts from "suggested edit" review queue. I got blocked yesterday and I am wondering why.

> Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18806698 wasn't helpful; please review the history of the post and consider how choosing a different action could've helped achieve that outcome more quickly.

I took a look at this review:

> Approved yesterday:
>
> Dennis C reviewed this yesterday: Approve
>
> Arek Żelechowski reviewed this yesterday: Approve

So basically, the edit was approved by me and original post author. None of the reviewers rejected and edit got approved. Why I got blocked?

I am not saying this was done for no reason - maybe I did something wrong. Maybe I was blocked because of other post and the wrong link is displayed?

Comment: I see the editor has (mis)used backticks where there are no inline code snippets. Its not useful IMO

Comment: You have approved an edit that you should have rejected. This edit made no sense - it used code blocks to highlight words and names and even parts of sentences. This edit should not have been accepted. Example: "for every ean number" is not code, it's a sentence, so it should not be embedded in a code block.

Comment: I would've voted "no improvement whatever" on this one.

Comment: `You` need to be more `careful` when reviewing. Read the `duplicate` questions that have been `linked` to this one and `review` more carefully.

Comment: *I can see that many reviewers do the same thing* Yes, unfortunately many users both use and approve of incorrect formatting. Low rep users do incorrect formatting changes for the rep, higher rep users approve the edits because they aren't paying attention, and it happens so often that other users, like yourself, end up thinking it's correct because you see it so often.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The edit applied `code markdown` for things that aren't code. If something is put in `code markdown`, this is meant to indicate that it is code. Code markdown should not be used it for highlighting.

The approval by an OP doesn't really mean much; many new users don't understand markdown, or how the review process works. Many of them Approve edits to their posts that should not be approved at all.

Since this review ban wasn't on a failure on a review audit, you weren't banned on audits. The review ban was given manually by a moderator. They pointed at this particular review as an example of an edit you should have rejected. There may be more that they disagree with.

There are [guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/168333). If you want to continue reviewing after the review ban has ended, then I would recommend reading those guidelines. That will help you to avoid further review bans.

And, as a tip: there is one other mistake I often see - people using quote markdown for things that aren't quotes.

> This markdown should only be applied to quoted text.

So, if you see quote markdown for things that aren't quotes, that too should be rejected.

Comment: Yeah, I can see this now. I still think that no explanation is somehow misleading (given the fact that edit was accepted anyway).
Also, I applied quote markdown initially, but it got edited and approved by someone else. How ironic, don't you think? Somebody did the same thing as I did. I honestly thought that approving this kind of thinks is ok, as I can see that many reviewers do the same thing - this post is another example of it.

Comment: @ArekŻelechowski that's Alanis Morissette irony ;) Coincidence/bad luck <> irony.